# How to Zip all folder in folder with password and remove folder after zip done?

Tags: command-line, directory, zip

[image]

How to zip all folder in Zip All Folder to New folder1.zip, New.folder2.zip, New_folder3.zip, Newfolder4.zip with password and auto remove folder after zip done.

I have used this code:

```bsh
for i in */; do
  zip --password pass -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"
done
```

It’s working good but it doesn't autoremove the folder when the zip is done.

Answer (score 3):

I would use srm to delete.

```
sudo apt-get install secure-delete

zip -P password -r targetFolder.zip targetFolder; srm -rv targetFolder
```

If you want to speed things up with less secure deletion, instead of 27 passes or random data written accross the files only a pass of zeros will be written:

```
zip -P password -r targetFolder.zip targetFolder; srm -fzrv targetFolder
```

One thing to take into consideration is:

- file-journaling type file systems
- swap
- hardware medium (SDD/HDD)

Read more here:

```
 man srm
```

[Gutmann_method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method)

Comment: thank you, it maybe help me.